# Find $\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$ given that $x=-8$, $y=9$, and $\frac{{dy}}{{dt}}=5$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this question on my homework assignment.

Assume that $x$ and $y$ are differentiable functions of $t$. Find $\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$ given that $x=-8$, $y=9$, and $\frac{{dy}}{{dt}}=5$. Equation: $y^2-x^2=17$.

There are examples in the book but not like this one where you have to find $\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$. I need to know how to solve a problem like this one.

Comment: Use chain rule of differentiation and (x^2-y^2) or (x^2+y^2) to calculate their value. Then, that way you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in basic implicit differentiation. Take the derivative of both sides of your equation, remembering how to differentiate an expression in $x$ when your independent variable is $t$. For example,
$$\begin{gathered}
  \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{x^2}} \right) = \frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {{x^2}} \right) \cdot \frac{{dx}}{{dt}} \\ 
   = 2x\frac{{dx}}{{dt}} \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
After you differentiate both sides of your equation, gather the terms that include $\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$ (you will have only one here), substitute in your value of $\frac{{dy}}{{dt}}$, and solve for $\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$. Do you need the details?

ADDED DETAILS:
$$\begin{align}
  {y^2} - {x^2} & = 17 \\ 
  \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{y^2}} \right) - \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{x^2}} \right) & = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {17} \right) \\ 
  \frac{d}{{dy}}\left( {{y^2}} \right)\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} - \frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {{x^2}} \right)\frac{{dx}}{{dt}} & = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {17} \right) \\ 
  2y\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} - 2x\frac{{dx}}{{dt}} & = 0 \\ 
  2x\frac{{dx}}{{dt}} & = 2y\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} \\ 
  \frac{{dx}}{{dt}} & = \frac{y}{x}\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} \\ 
  &  = \frac{9}{{ - 8}} \cdot 5 \\ 
  &  = \frac{{ - 45}}{8} \\ 
\end{align}$$

In actual problem solving you would leave out some of these steps.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}$ and then using the chain rule:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$

So
$$2y - 2x\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = 0
\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{y}{x}$$

Since $y = 9$, and $x= -8$,
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{9}{-8}.$$

Now solve for $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$ using the fact that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = 5$ and
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}. $$